# Error trying to use Tinymce plugin with webpack encore

Tags: javascript, symfony, module, tinymce, webpack-encore

I'm trying to use the Tinymce plugin on a textarea element:

```
<textarea id="reportDescription" name="reportDescription" class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea>
```

Im working with Symfony and Webpack Encore. So I installed the package using:

```
yarn add tinymce
```

In webpack.config.js I coded:

```
.copyFiles({
        from: 'node_modules/tinymce/skins',
        to: 'skins/[path]/[name].[ext]'
    })
```

And in the .js where I'm trying to initialize the plugin:

```
require('tinymce');

$(document).ready(function () {
   
    if($("#reportDescription").length > 0){
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea#reportDescription"
            
        });
    }
});
```

When I load my page on my browser, I get this error:

```
tinymce.js:4680 
    GET http://url/build/models/dom/model.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tinymce.js:18181 
    Failed to load model: dom from url models/dom/model.js
tinymce.js:4680 
    GET http://url/build/icons/default/icons.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tinymce.js:18181 
    Failed to load icons: default from url http://url/build/icons/default/icons.js
tinymce.js:4680 
    GET http://url/build/themes/silver/theme.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tinymce.js:18181 
    Failed to load theme: silver from url themes/silver/theme.js
```

I don't understand very well yet how to work with modules on webpack. How to import them, when to use require or import and the difference between them. So maybe I'm missing something important.

Comment: If you don't mind which WYSIWYG you use, there is a symfony documentation with another one here: https://symfony.com/bundles/FOSCKEditorBundle/current/index.html

Answer (score 2):

the set up I have is as follows

1. install copy webpack plugin  -- *yarn add copy-webpack-plugin --dev*
2. In webpack.config.js

   ```
   const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");  // at the top
   // ...
   // ... other stuff

   Encore.addPlugin(
    new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            context: './node_modules/tinymce/',
            from: '**/*.(min.js|min.css|woff)',
            to: './tinymce/[path][name][ext]'
          }
        ]
      })
    );

   Encore
      // directory where compiled assets will be stored
      .setOutputPath('public/build/')
      // other code
   ```
3. I use stimulusjs so in the stimulus controller (tiny_controller.js) I have the code below so that all textareas with tinymce class will be matched

   ```
    import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";
    import tinymce from 'tinymce/tinymce';
    // other code
    // other code
    initialize() {
        this.defaults = {
            base_url: '/build/tinymce',
            plugins: 'preview importcss',
            menubar: 'view insert format tools table',
            toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic'
            toolbar_sticky: false,
            suffix: '.min'
        };
    }   

    connect() {
        this.initTinyMCE();
    }

    initTinyMCE() {
        let config = Object.assign({
            selector: 'textarea.tinymce',
        }, this.defaults);
        tinymce.init(config);
    }
    //other code
    //other code
   ```

Finally in the HTML Form it could be something like this

```
<div data-controller="tiny">
    <textarea name="comment" class="tinymce">Enter text here..</textarea> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst @Patrick Kenekayoro posted a really nice answer, in your scenario the issue is the path. As you can notice, it looks for `/build/models/...`, so to resolve this simply copy/paste the below code to your webpack config:

```
.copyFiles({
    from: 'node_modules/tinymce/skins',
    to: 'skins/[path]/[name].[ext]'
})

.copyFiles({
    from: 'node_modules/tinymce/models',
    to: 'models/[path]/[name].[ext]'
})

.copyFiles({
    from: 'node_modules/tinymce/plugins',
    to: 'plugins/[path][name].[ext]',
    includeSubdirectories: true,
    pattern: /.*/
})

.copyFiles({
    from: 'node_modules/tinymce/icons',
    to: 'icons/[path][name].[ext]',
    includeSubdirectories: true,
    pattern: /.*/
})
```

This worked for me really well even in the latest Symfony projects.